# Idiomatic way to wrap object into collection (if it's not a collection already) in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have (for instance) a mix of data structures such as `{:name "Peter" :children "Mark"}` and `{:name "Mark" :children ["Julia" "John"]` i.e. :children value is either a single string or a collection of strings. Other functions in my code expect that the value of :children is always a collection of strings, so I need to adapt the data for them.
Of course I can use something like:

```
(defn data-adapter [m]
  (let [children (:children m)]
    (assoc m :children 
             (if (coll? children) 
               children
               [children]))))
```

But is there a more idiomatic/laconic way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will have to take no for an answer.

`(if (coll? x) x [x])` is about as terse and expressive as it gets. It’s what people usually use for this problem (sometimes with `sequential?` instead of `coll?`).

`cond->` enthusiasts like me sometimes try to use it in place of a simple conditional, but here it is no improvement:

```
(cond-> x (not (coll? x)) vector)
```

In the context of your code, however, you can do a little better. A lookup and association is best expressed with `update`:

```
(defn data-adapter [m]
  (update m :children #(if (coll? %) % [%])))
```

Answer (score 1):

the only advice would be to abstract that logic to some function, to keep your actual business logic clean.

```
(defn data-adapter [m]
  (let [children (:children m)]
    (assoc m :children (ensure-coll children))))
```

or, more concise, with `update`:

```
(defn data-adapter [m]
  (update m :children ensure-coll))
```

where `ensure-coll` could be something like this:

```
(defn iffun [check & {:keys [t f] :or {t identity f identity}}]
  #((if (check %) t f) %))

(def ensure-coll (iffun coll? :f list))
```

(or whatever another implementation you like)

```
user> (data-adapter {:children 1})
;;=> {:children (1)}

user> (data-adapter {:children [1]})
;;=> {:children [1]}
```

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps not idiomatic, but laconic:

```clj
(flatten [x])
```

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/flatten

Comment: Maybe you can explain how your solution works for the OP problem. I read the documentation and couldn't find a way to use `flatten` to wrap non-collections into collections

Comment: This will flatten out `x` if it's a deeply nested collection.