# What’s the idiomatic way to guarantee some unknown value is inside a sequence?

Tags: clojure, flatten

What’s the idiomatic way to guarantee some unknown value is inside a sequence, where that value could or could not already be in a sequence? `(into [] val)` fails if val isn't already in a seq `(conj [] val)` always works but might nest, i.e. `[[val...]]` (oh and not be nested, if already in a seq)* is it simply `(flatten (conj`?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? You know val for sure, but you dont know if the thing you get is someting you can val append to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Idiomatic way to wrap object into collection (if it's not a collection already) in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59453099/idiomatic-way-to-wrap-object-into-collection-if-its-not-a-collection-already)

Answer (score 6):

This sort of thing -- working with a value that may or may not be a sequence -- is just not idiomatic. See https://stuartsierra.com/2015/06/10/clojure-donts-heisenparameter where he specifically calls this out.

Refactor your code so `val` is either always a sequence or never a sequence. You should "never" have code that can produce both.

Answer (score 0):

`(conj [] val)` will always return `[val]`, never `[[val]]`.

If `val` itself is a vector, then yes, `(conj [] val)` will return a vector of one element, where that one element is the vector `val`.

Comment: If you have `val` that might be a non-collection like 7, or it might be a vector `[7]`, or it might be a list `(7)`, and in any of those cases you want to add the number 7 to a sequence, then I think you need to write conditional code, perhaps using conditions like `(vector? val)` or `(coll? val)`, and do different things depending on whether `val` is a sequence/vector, or not.